# margin errors on IE 8 but perfect on firefox

Tags: internet-explorer-8, margin

I absolutely do not know how to fix the margin errors caused by IE 8.  The website below looks fine on firefox but all the content of the right sidebar goes down at the bottom of the page when you open it with IE.

http://www.mindanaowomen.org/mcw/

please help!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you run IE8 in compatibility (quirks of forgiving mode) it works okay.

Your markup is not well formatted. You have an unnecesary closing  in the second last div of class type "entry" that throws the IE 8 parser.

```
<p>
The Iligan ACG, through the radio program, also partnered with groups such as the
             .......
also taken up in partnership with PIA.</span>
</p>
```

Take out this and your markup might work. I also picked up some other bad markup in one of your links (note the unpaired quotation mark at the end of the img definition):

```
<a href="http://www.mindanaowomen.org/mcw/?page_id=120">
```

There were also a few XHTML validation errors that should be looked at, for example you should not nest div elements inside of P elements.